# Background color of opaque navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, uisplitview

I have very strange trouble, on my mind, with background color of navigation bar.
I have splitview with master and detail. So master navigation bar is opaque #1C4E65 color. When i set this color as a tint color of UIView, then colors is different.
I have a couple of screens:
[image: First screenshot with navigation bar]
[image: My view with that color]
[image: Difference in result]

Comment: watch for the navigation controller navigation bar color

Comment: Navigation bar color is driving via barTintColor property, there is another trouble.